# Why does my excel Button Macro work on my computer but not on another computer

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivot table with 3 slicers and I wanted to make it easy for anyone to filter with the slicers and with one click, clear all filters, so I created a button using code I found on Microsoft's website below. It works perfectly fine on my computer, but once I open it on my colleagues computer it won't work.

My colleague and I changed his trusted connections/Macros settings and it worked, however this defeats the purpose, as people who get the report are not excel experts and I don't have access or control over their settings

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim cache As SlicerCache
    For Each cache In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
    cache.ClearManualFilter
    Next cache
End Sub
```

The error says

> *Cannot run the macro. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.*

Please help

Comment: Other user's macro security settings is not something you can have control over. If you were able to control these settings, it would also defeat the purpose of it being an application setting to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Usually MS office is defaulted to block macros. Users will have to go into their settings and change their settings to disable macros with notifications. This way when they open the file they will have a pop-up with the option to enable macros on the file you sent.

Macros can be extremely deadly and used as a trojan horse to load viruses to a system, this is why it is best they are disabled with notification. Only macros from a trusted source should be enabled if you receive a notification. I will suggest you create a step-by-step guide for users to instruct them on how to change their settings.

Comment: Well I was wondering if there was a different way to make the functionality

Comment: Only way I can think of is if you consider a non VBA option. You can't force a Macro to run on a machine, unless that machine allows all Macros.